# Restrict S3 Object Access to Specific Cognito Users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I am working on an application that will manage access to purchased files that are stored in S3. I have files organized by product in S3, for example:

```
my-bucket
  ├── product-a
  │     ├── file-1
  │     ├── file-2
  │     └── file-3
  ├── product-b
  │     ├── file-1
  │     ├── file-2
  │     └── file-3
  └── etc...
```

I am also using Cognito to manage user identities and authentication. I would like to create an IAM role that all users will assume which will grant them access only to the files of products they have purchased. What would be the proper way to do this? I have read thru [Cognito's documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/cognito/) and I feel I am just not quite connecting the dots.

I see from [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_examples.html#iam-policy-example-cognito) example, that I could provide each user access to their own folder in a bucket, but then I would have to copy the files to each user's folder, which seems both inefficient and prone to error.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
   {
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
     "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"],
      "Condition": {"StringLike": {"s3:prefix": ["cognito/myapp/"]}}
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/myapp/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}",
        "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/myapp/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But I was hoping to create a policy that would grant a user access to the folder of `product-a` if and only if they had purchased that product, say using some flag that was contained in that user's Cognito Sync data.

Is this possible? Am I just not using the correct tools? I think this must be a common use-case.

Comment: What is the identity provider for your user base, Cognito User Pools/Facebook/Google any other? Does it have certain claims?

Comment: I am using User Pools. So yeah, I get tokens with claims. Will this help me?

Comment: @sethro did you find a solution to this - I'm trying to build a similar system. Thanks.

Comment: @NickAger, I didn't. The approach I ended up going with was to instead have a server generate temporary pre-signed URLs when a user requested access to a file that the server determined they had access to. Still not sure this can't all be accomplished with Cognito, but I gave up.

Comment: @sethro or anyone else had any joy finding a solution to this?

Comment: Any solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

In my use case, this was possible because of the following:

1. I upload a file to s3
2. I have a lambda listening to S3 events that interprets this file created and creates an entry in DynamoDB (our app's database engine). However, this entry contains a url to access this file which is not the s3 url. Instead it's an API gateway url that proxies the request and has a custom lambda authorizer on it. This lambda authorizer then validates user access by looking at the cognito token and lets me add completely fine-grained access for other users whilst still letting the core user / owner manage the file using the S3 sdk client directly and with the correct cognito Identity roles attached to the bucket permissions.
3. the user then requests this image with the Authorization cognito token header in the request, this is processed by API gateway and the relevant response is returned.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be Aws Presigned URLs [Read more here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-presigned-url.html#PresignedUrlUploadObject-LimitCapabilities). The idea is you request a temporary url in order to give an access to the specific s3 objects with an expiration time.